# How to associate a pre-existing billing account with a new app engine project in Google cloud console?

Tags: google-app-engine, billing, google-cloud-console

I have a pre-existing billing account for an earlier project, that works fine.

How can I associate a new project with that same account?

In the Google Developer Console, if I select the new project and try to enable billing it gives me the forms to create a new billing account. I did not find a way to associate the project's billing to the existing account.

If I look at the existing billing account I can see my earlier project in the list of projects but have found no way add a new project to the account.

Comment: I dont think you can....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have enabled billing for one of my applications already, why do I have to do it again for my other apps?
>
> We want to provide developers with fine-grained control over each of
>   their applications. They may wish to have a separate budget for
>   different apps, or apps that run entirely on free quota, rather than a
>   single budget for each.

[DOCUMENTATION](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/billing?hl=fr#perapp)

Comment: thanks! for Paul Collngwood as well.

i was reading the docs but did not find this point. the console shows a list of projects like there could be multiple so it is very confusing that there actually can be only one. in the billing account listing there even is the field for # of projects for account -- why is that even there if it's always 1? weird. anyhow thanks now i know that simply must duplicate the infos.

Comment: I find it very odd that google still doesn't support google wallet por billing. I have to re-enter all the details again every time i enable billing. It should just be 'use my wallet'

Comment: App engine is awesome and well built. Their billing module is their Achilles heel.

Answer (score 2):

Try hitting cancel at the end when it asks you to choose a name for the news billing account. After I did that I was able to associate my second project with my primary billing account. I also noticed some weirdness with a billing account that was in trial mode. Once I "upgraded" this billing account I think I could associate other projects with it.

Of course make sure you are an admin for the billing account and all projects you wish to associate with that billing.